# How can I update my data automatically in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have a code block in my class

```
def datas(self):               
        
  source = requests.get("http://150.150.150.150/tek.json").json()  
  return source
```

My program uses this data and this data is updated in that server everyday at 12:05 AM.
When i run app at 12:00 and if i wait untill 12:10 the datas is not updated in my app.
Only if i restart the app then new data pulls from my app.

I used While True and sleep for 10 but this caused the program to wait every 10 seconds to run.

How can i fix this issue. Should i use Clock Schedule? I don't know how to use. Could you please help me? I want to apdate data in every 10 seceonds so new datas can seen on the screen.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case what could be helpful is an asyncio library. It would the While True loop to run every 10 seconds without freezing the whole program.

Here is an example:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/async/asyncio_basic.py?fbclid=IwAR0Ae1UhdZL57ytHdVzpXYiPUnxE1c5si6RWnYQjo5l_N-Wm3MTNbGJDsok

And if that does not work for you there are plenty videos on YTB from "Tech with Tim" for example that shows you how to set methods in asyncio .

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Clock` object looks like the easiest way to solve your problem. To execute your function retrieving data every 10 seconds, you can use:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

def datas(self):
  source = requests.get("http://150.150.150.150/tek.json").json()  
  return source

Clock.schedule_interval(datas, 10)
```

However, I don't really get why you want to retrieve the data every 10s if you know it's updated only once per day. To me, it would make more sense to schedule the Clock for every 60s, check whether it's 12:06 for instance, and only do the request if it's the case (otherwise do nothing)